# Assigning values to torch tensors

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to assign some values to a torch tensor. In the sample code below, I initialized a tensor U and try to assign a tensor b to its last 2 dimensions. In reality, this is a loop over i and j that solves some relation for a number of training data (here 10) and assigns it to its corresponding location.

```
import torch

U = torch.zeros([10, 1, 4, 4])
b = torch.rand([10, 1, 1, 1])

i = 2
j = 2
U[:, :, i, j] = b
```

I was expecting vector b to be assigned for dimensions i and j of corresponding training data (shape of training data being (10,1)) but it gives me an error. The error that I get is the following

```
RuntimeError: expand(torch.FloatTensor{[10, 1, 1, 1]}, size=[10, 1]): the number of sizes provided (2) must be greater or equal to the number of dimensions in the tensor (4)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it would be appreciated.

---

As an example, you can think of this as if '[10, 1]' is the shape of my data. Imagine it is 10 images, each of which has one channel. Then imagine each image is of shape '[4, 4]'. In each iteration of the loop, pixel '[i, j]' for all images and channels is being calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `b` tensor has too much dimensions.

`U[:, :, i, j]` has a `[10, 1]` shape (try `U[:, :, i, j].shape`)

Use `b = torch.rand([10, 1])` instead.

Comment: You are right, I think using squeeze would be the best way to reshape my b tensor to fix the issue (as I don't define tensor b myself in the actual code) and reduce dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Khoyo's tip on the source of the problem, I used `reshape` to fix this as following

```
import torch

U = torch.zeros([10, 1, 4, 4])
b = torch.rand([10, 1, 1, 1])

i = 2
j = 2
U[:, :, i, j] = b.reshape((-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a shape mismatch in your assignment. `U[..., [i], [j]]` will do the same meanwhile keep the last two dimensions for you.